# how to remove(or not use) launch screen storyboard in xcode with swift

Tags: ios, swift, launch-screen

i make some app.
the app does not using storyboard. only prommatically.

also i want to not using launch screen.

so, delete launch row in plist.
The result is.... top and bottom screen is black space...
and start black screen...

how to remove launch screen?? 
(or how to make launch screen using code prommatically?)

i want the app is ...
  app icontouch ->  mainview(collectionview) -> window addsubviw  loading animation(UIView Anima...)....-> dismiss -> mainview

now....
app icontouch -> launch screen!!!!! -> mainview(collectionview) -> window addsubviw  loading animation(UIView Anima...).....-> dismiss -> mainview

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must have a launch screen, either provided by a storyboard or using images in an asset catalog.  If you remove both of these then iOS will assume that your app doesn't support larger displays, which is why you are getting the black bars; your app is running in backward-compatibility mode.

Since the launch screen is shown while your app is loading, it cannot be created programatically; your app isn't yet running.

If you want to animate the launch screen then your need your launch storyboard scene or your launch image to be identical to your first view.  You can then animate this first view

Comment: what do you mean by "your launch storyboard scene or your launch image to be identical to your first view" . can you please explain it more?

Comment: You make the scene in your launch storyboard identical to the initial scene in your main storyboard. Then there will be a seamless transition between the static launch scene and a scene where you can execute code.

Comment: Since iOS 14 you can get rid of the launch screen storyboard! Basic configuration of the launch screen can be done using an Info.plist entry "Launch Screen" (=UILaunchScreen) where you can add configuration for the background color, navigation bar, tab bar and an image to be shown.

Answer (score -1):

I opened launchscreen storyboard in the text edtior, then removed the **< viewcontroller >** tag and left other tags since storyboard is important for ios projects it seems. thanks to @Paulw11

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35451415)